# Conditionally select data from store or API in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx

Suppose the following route:

`/cars/3`

If I were going to edit this item, I could simply include the edit form in the template and pass the car item as an input, like so:

`<edit-car [car]="car"></edit-car>`

If I utilize the following route instead:

`/cars/3/edit-car`

That component needs to receive the car item's information. If I've navigated from the detail component to the edit component, then it is no problem to grab the car item info from the store:

`car$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getCar)`

However, if someone browses to `/cars/3` and then changes the route to `/cars/4/edit-car`, the edit component would still be populated with Car 3's information.

In that case, I need to go fetch Car 4's information from the API.

Why would someone change the url parameters arbitrarily? I don't know. I'm just curious what my options are for solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with some pretty neat interactions with the router. For example your router would look like this

```
{ path: 'editcar', component: editcar, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateService] },
{ path: 'editcar/:id', component: editcar, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateService] }
```

Then in your ngOnInit you can use a subscription to monitor the URL route
You'll need to import `import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';`

```
this.routeSubscription = this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  if (+params['id'] >= 0) {
    this.selectedCar = +params['id'];
  } else {
    this.selectedCar = 1; //default
  }
```

From there its all about calling your API with `this.selectedCar`